# Setting configuration parameters from a IO Monad - design pattern

Tags: haskell, configuration, io

I would like my question to be a general one, actually I'm working with web API querying using wreq more specifically. The Web service requests some bearer <> token authorization, I manage to post a request

`r = post (serveraddress ++ "/api/Integration/Login") (toJSON (AuthDataStruct "user" "xxxxxx"))`

I get then a response `r` from which I'm able to extract a "token_type" and a "access_token"

```
accessToken = r >>= (\ x -> return $ x ^. responseBody . key "access_token" . _String)
tokenType = r >>= (\ x -> return $ x ^. responseBody . key "token_type" . _String)
```

but these data are of IO type (IO Text - precisely) the thing is that this data are needed to build a Authorization header

```
authHeader :: IO Network.Wreq.Options
authHeader = do
     tk <- tokenType
     at <- accessToken
     let auth = AccessToken (unpack tk) (unpack at)
     return (opts auth)
```

`opts token = defaults & header "Authorization" .~ [BI.packChars (tokenType token ++ " " ++ accessToken token)]`

which is then used for every single request made to the web service:

```
webQueryGetProperties :: IO (Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
webQueryGetProperties = do`
     opt <- authHeader 
     let sql = GetDocument 1 ""  
     postWith opt (serveraddress ++ "/api/Integration/GetProperties") (toJSON sql)



webQueryGetDataValues etc...
```

Don't pay to much attention to the code try to follow my reasoning, I would like to set-up a configuration data structure to store the token information in order to avoid to run all the IO just to get what I already have... (it's a waste of ressources, not DRYI) the token just need to be renewed after a certain lapse of time.
The ideal would be to have a configuration builder which creates a stored token data type with the data extracted from the IO action. And if I'm not wrong it's not possible in Haskell (cannot escape the monad), what are the possible solution:

- keeping all the code in the same IO monad in order to have access for all the plethora of requests to the authorization token? but how it's deal with "purity" I am stuck in an impure IO in all my code
- using IORef?
- other pattern?

In an imperative language you just take the token data from the result and give it to a constructor and you have a "global" configuration set once for all.

Answer (score 1):

The low-tech pattern is to simply accept your configuration as an argument.

```
webQueryGetProperties :: Options -> IO (Response ByteString)
webQueryGetProperties o = postWith o (...) (...)
```

Yes, *everything* that depends on the configuration, even transitively, must take it as an argument.

Then, at the top-level, you build the configuration once.

```
main = do
    o <- authHeader
    webQueryGetProperties o
    webQueryGetDataValues o
    -- etc.
```

Sometimes it is convenient to use `ReaderT` to pass the argument around for you. Notably, this makes it possible to write actions that don't need the argument in a way that's oblivious to the fact they're actually passing the argument around for you.

```
webQueryGetProperties :: ReaderT Options IO (Response ByteString)
webQueryGetProperties = do
    o <- ask
    liftIO (postWith o (...) (...))

doesn'tNeedOptions :: MonadIO m => IO String
doesn'tNeedOptions = liftIO $ do
    putStrLn "wow"
    getLine

main = do
    o <- authHeader
    flip runReaderT o $ do
        webQueryGetProperties
        doesn'tNeedOptions -- configuration gets passed to this but ignored automatically
        webQueryGetDataValues
```

Actually, in this style, one would normally write a bit more class-polymorphic, so

```
webQueryGetProperties :: (MonadReader Options m, MonadIO m) => m (Response ByteString)
-- implementation doesn't change
```

If you will need to be able to notice that the token has expired and needs to be replaced with a different token, you can upgrade to `StateT`.

```
webQueryGetProperties :: (MonadState Options m, MonadIO m) => m (Response ByteString)
webQueryGetProperties = do
    o <- get
    liftIO (postWith o (...) (...))

checkAndRenew :: (MonadState Options m, MonadIO m) => m ()
checkAndRenew = do
    renewp <- gets needsToBeRenewed
    when renewp (authHeader >>= put)
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was also thinking to refactor the code to mtl (ReaderT) - but nevertheless in order to avoid numerous querying for requesting the token I need to stay in one function (i.e. in one "do evaluation") - in reality my configuration isn't "stored" in the program but on the remote server and is just "asked" by the program.

Comment: @user3680029 I guess I don't understand the question, then. What do you want your program to do with the configuration after asking the remote server for it, if not "store" and use it?

Comment: You didn't misunderstand - I was just asking myself if there's a recommended way to have it stored in a "non IO" variable  - using for example a function : IO Response -> IO () which as a side effect will under the hood populate a "globish" kind of variable.

Comment: @user3680029 No.